# Reading file by many threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, readfile

I have a study assignment, I need to create programm in java which able to read .txt file by many threads and each thread need to add it's ID to the end of each row in the file. As I result I need to get same txt file with threads ID.
I had many attempts, but I coudn't compel each thread to read just unique line.

This is study task, so I can do this only under specified conditions.

Can you tell me how best way to solve this problem.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, you don't get that help here. If you could let us know what all you have done, then we will be able to help you

Comment: If you have code that isn't working, as you say, then you should post that code and ask a question about that. Just asking people to write your code is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by using LinkedHashMap and using synchronuzed methods.
Strings which were readed by threads were put into LinkedHashMap with threads ID, then were united and wrote to result file.